# Printing the current value and previous value between the date range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a sample data like this

```
ID     DATE           TIME     STATUS 
---------------------------------------------
A      01-01-2000     0900     ACTIVE 
A      05-02-2000     1000     INACTIVE 
A      01-07-2000     1300     ACTIVE 
B      01-05-2005     1000     ACTIVE 
B      01-08-2007     1050     ACTIVE
C      01-01-2010     0900     ACTIVE 
C      01-07-2010     1900     INACTIVE
```

From the above data set, if we only focus on `ID='A'` we note that `A` was initally active, then became inactive on `05-02-2000` and then it was inactive until `01-07-2000`.

Which means that `A` was inactive from `05-Feb-2000` to `01-July-2000`.

My questions are:

1. if I execute a query with `(ID=A, Date=01-04-2000)` it should give me

   ```
   A      05-02-2000     1000     INACTIVE
   ```

   because since that date is not available in that data set, it should search for the previous one and print that
2. Also, if my condition is `(ID=A, Date=01-07-2000)` it should not only print the value which is present in the table, but also print a previous value

   ```
   A      05-02-2000     1000     INACTIVE 
   A      01-07-2000     1300     ACTIVE
   ```

I would really appreciate if any one can assist me solve this query. I am trying my best to solve this.

Thank you every one.

Any take on this?

Afaq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
SELECT ID, Date, Time, Status
 from (select ID, Date, Time, Status, row_number() over (order by Date) Ranking
        from MyTable
        where ID = @SearchId
         and Date <= @SearchDate) xx
 where Ranking < 3
 order by Date, Time
```

This will return at most two rows. Its not clear if you are using Date and Time datatyped columns, or if you are actually using reserved words as column names, so you'll have to fuss with that.  (I left out Time, but you could easily add that to the various orderings and filterings.)

---

Given the revised criteria, it gets a bit trickier, as the inclusion or exclusion of a row depends upon the value returned in a different row. Here, the “second” row, if there are two or more rows, is included only if the “first” row equals a particular value. The standard way to do this is to query the data to get the max value, then query it again while referencing the result of the first set.

However, you can do a lot of screwy things with row_number. Work on this:

```
SELECT ID, Date, Time, Status
 from (select
          ID, Date, Time, Status
         ,row_number() over (partition by case when Date = @SearchDate then 0 else 1 end
                             order by     case when Date = @SearchDate then 0 else 1 end
                                         ,Date) Ranking
        from MyTable
        where ID = @SearchId
         and Date <= @SearchDate) xx
 where Ranking = 1
 order by Date, Time
```

You'll have to resolve the date/time issue, since this only works against dates.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer Philip, but here I need to be more specific about the output I am getting. We need to modify this solution in such a way that if the exact date matches it should print the same result and also the immediate previous one; but if it doesnt, it should print only the previous one. Can you please look into this condition.

Comment: Thanks again Philip.. yes my date columns are date data type and they are named different. I mentioned them here for reference only. Btw, I did not understand the new query you gave here. What is the data import date here?

Comment: I really appreciate the time you are giving me. looking forward for the solution

Comment: I was writing/testing the *form* of the query against one of my own tables, which has a "DataImportDate" column. I've edited the query to just reference the "base" date column.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to pull a row if, for the specified date, it is:

1) the last record, or

2) the last *inactive* record.

And the two conditions may match the same row as well as two distinct rows.

Here's how this logic could be implemented in SQL Server 2005+:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    ID,
    Date,
    Time,
    Status,
    RankOverall  = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (                    ORDER BY Date DESC),
    RankByStatus = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Status ORDER BY Date DESC)
  FROM Activity
  WHERE ID = @ID
    AND Date <= @Date
)
SELECT
  ID,
  Date,
  Time,
  Status,
FROM ranked
WHERE RankOverall = 1
   OR Status = 'INACTIVE' AND RankByStatus = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Andriy for your Answer, but I did not understand why did you partition over Status. Its not important for me. I explained Status in context to date and the activity continuation. I tried your answer and I am somehow close.

Comment: In your case I checked that if I do not put any condition over the ID... I do not get the output... assume my input condition to be just the date or a date range...

Comment: Take an example I input a question like this: Show me all ID and their records between the date range 20-02-2010 to 22-02-2010. It should show me the result of ID=A is ACTIVE, ID=B as Active and ID=C as Active. Here ID=C cannot be Inactive because it went inactive in the month of July. Consider my date column as date datatype

Comment: I really appreciate the time you are giving me. looking forward for the solution

Comment: @Afaq: Well, my solution can be easily extended to multiple IDs: just add `PARTITION BY ID` to the `RankOverall` calculation and change `PARTITION BY Status` to `PARTITION BY ID, Status` in the calculation of `RankByStatus`. Your second change to the original question seems more substantial, though, and may require another solution (which means you might need to ask that as a new question).

Comment: Thank you Andriy, I have started a new question on this. Thanks for your post.