# Printing the records between the date range and also the last record if not in date range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have had asked this question on my previous question post 
[Printing the current value and previous value between the date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739147/printing-the-current-value-and-previous-value-between-the-date-range)
But this time I want to be more specific about the date range here.

As you see I have the below data set:

```
    ID     DATE           TIME     STATUS 
    ---------------------------------------------
    A      01-01-2000     0900     ACTIVE 
    A      05-02-2000     1000     INACTIVE 
    A      01-07-2000     1300     ACTIVE 
    B      01-05-2005     1000     ACTIVE 
    B      01-08-2007     1050     ACTIVE
    C      01-01-2010     0900     ACTIVE
    C      01-05-2010     0800     INACTIVE
    C      01-07-2010     1900     ACTIVE
```

I want all the ID between this following date range (01-04-2010 to 01-06-2010). The output should be:

```
ID     DATE           TIME     STATUS 
---------------------------------------------
A      01-07-2000     1300     ACTIVE 
B      01-08-2007     1050     ACTIVE
C      01-01-2010     0900     ACTIVE 
C      01-05-2010     0800     INACTIVE
```

The idea is if you see the last record of every ID no matter if it does not belong to that date range because I want the status to show that since that particular date the ID=A status has not changed. Also, if you see ID=C both the date belongs to the date range so shall print both.

PS: The DATE is in the DATE format and in MS SQL

I would appreciate if any one can give their take on this. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `SET DATEFORMAT ymd` and query below:

```
DATEFORMAT ymd

SELECT customerName 
FROM dbo.customer 
WHERE insertedDate BETWEEN '2010-04-01 'AND '2010-06-01'
```

Comment: This will print date range between the date specified... But I want the last record of each ID.. Please see the question

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want:

1. Any ID whose status within the specified range, and
2. The most recent active status not in

Here, I'm calling your source table `STATS`:

```
DECLARE @START DATE = '1/4/2010';
DECLARE @END DATE = '1/6/2010';

; WITH a AS (
    SELECT *,r=ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [ID],[STATUS] ORDER BY [DATE] DESC, [TIME] DESC)
    FROM [STATS]
)
SELECT [ID], [DATE], [TIME], [STATUS] FROM a
WHERE [DATE] BETWEEN @START AND @END

UNION

SELECT [ID], [DATE], [TIME], [STATUS] FROM a
WHERE [STATUS]='ACTIVE'
AND r=1;
```

Result:

```
ID   DATE       TIME STATUS
---- ---------- ---- ----------------
A    2000-01-07 1300 ACTIVE
B    2007-01-08 1050 ACTIVE
C    2010-01-05 0800 INACTIVE
C    2010-01-07 1900 ACTIVE
```